# How to create bootable DOS USB stick which sees NTFS drives?

Tags: usb, boot, ntfs, bootable-media, ms-dos

How to create bootable DOS USB stick which sees NTFS drives ?

I've found ntfs4dos.exe by Mark Russinovich, but I don't know how to use it with dos.
Also I've found many ways to create DOS bootable USB sticks, but many of them simply aren't working. So, my question consists of 2 parts:

1)Create bootable and WORKING DOS USB stick,
2)How to make it, to enable NTFS drives and work with them.

Comment: Have you looked at FreeDOS? http://www.freedos.org/ - I'm moderately sure it has an NTFS filesystem driver.

Comment: AFAIK FreeDOS does not support NTFS without 3rd party drivers such as Ntfs4Dos. @SEARAS: What do you need this for exactly, that you cannot accomplish using a LiveXP (WinPE/BartPE) USB/CD for example?

Comment: i believe free version of WinISO can edit bootable CD images, so you can add tools like NTFS readers to DOS or WinPE LiveCDs of choice. Not to LiveDVDs though. Why it can be needed - for example because SiliconImage/Adaptec HostRAID cards only have 16-bit DOS-based firmware flashers, that you can not run from other OSes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. After a long month of googling and researching (from Sep 27 to Oct 20), I've found driver by Paragon, and could get it working.
1) create MS-DOS boot floppy image (I think you already know how to do it...)
2) copy this driver
3) create an ISO (for example, with UltraISO), and put floppy image there
4) create a batch file, which mounts floppy image in virtual drive , using Rawwrite.exe
5) set that batch as ISO's bootable file
6) write your ISO to floppy , using tools like WinToFlash

This driver's specifications:

1) It can read/write NTFS drives
2) It is very very small. (NTFSDos needs many files and much space)
3) It doesn't need `Autorun.bat` or `Config.sys`. It just needs you to run *mount.bat*.
4) It's silent. (NTFSDos's free versions always show smtg)
5) You can even copy it to floppy, just by creating an MS-DOS boot disk!
6) It runs almost in all MS-DOSes.
7) In this [**link**](http://www.fdd5-25.net/drivers/ntfs-paragon.zip) it's **FREE** to download :)

I think this can help a lot of people, who don't want to search everywhere;)
Good luck !

Answer (score 2):

1. Find an tool called **HPUSBDisk.exe** (Google it)
2. Download a MS-DOS bootdisk. Find it here: http://www.allbootdisks.com/download/me.html
   They are in .img format, and you need the files inside so you you need an application which can **extract .img files like [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html).** Unpack it.
3. Run HPUSBDisk.exe **as admin**, and format your USB-drive with **Fat32**, and tick "**Create a DOS startup disk using system files located at:**" Point to the path you just extracted to. And press Start.
4. Find and download "**ntfs-paragon.zip**" (Google it) and then extract and copy ntfs-paragon.zip to your USB-drive, so all **contents are in the root folder**.
5. That's all basically,  now just copy all you DOS-tools you need to the USB-drive (like ghost, format, xcopy etc) and it should be bootable. To mount NTFS drive, just type mount.bat.

Tip: If you want it automatically mount ntfs when your booting, you can create a 
    file called autoexec.bat and put this in it:

```
@echo off
mount.bat
```

Comment: Worked for me. The only bad thing is that the diskedit.exe tool which I wanted to apply for NTFS disks appeared to work only for FAT.