# How do I recover data from hard disk of Windows

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, data-recovery

1. Internal hard-drive is completely fine.
2. My Windows 8.1 don't reboot, it shows error that `system32/winload` is missing.
3. When I try to install windows on other primary hard-drive (D:/), It completes steps of Installation but again displays error after
   reboot. (When PC reboots start Windows setup)
4. I tried to install Windows 7, 8.1
5. No Refresh, Reset or any other troubleshoot method is working (even with command prompt it only states that no windows is found,
   however when you choose to boot into other OS, It lists 6 Windows OS
   which somehow is the number of attempts on windows installation I
   did)
6. Doesn't work even with recovery tools.
7. I know internal hard-drive is fine because I can see my data when I try to recover it using "Disk Management Recovery" by Windows.

But I can't recover it . Please help, I don't know elsewhere to go. And there are no tech shops near my home within miles.

Thanks!

*Why this question is not a duplicate:*

I am asking to recover data from a non-bootable windows. My hard-drive is absolutely fine.
The data as I said, is not lost and is there. This is not a mechanical failure.

Comment: How did you try to reinstall the OS and how did it fail?

Comment: I was using ubuntu before, I completely format that drive, Installed Windows 8.1 from fresh, used it quite well for a week and one day I accidentally turned it off, without the normal shutdown procedure (long press power button). Problem happened since then.

Comment: Actually its not remotely similar. Please see my question.

Comment: Boot into linux and backup your data from the windows locations of your choosing to a removable media. Flash drive, External HDD and then reinstall windows.

Comment: Thanks @NetworkKingPin but I installed fresh OS, no linux of Grun loader remains in my system, however I guess I can use portable ubuntu via a flash drive and backup my hard drive that way. Thanks mate!

Comment: @NetworkKingPin pls add this answer so that i can select it.

Comment: @Rees I will add that in there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Rees said.

**You can install a fresh OS. Shouldve thought about that too. Another thing is if you do not want to install a fresh OS you can do the Following.**

**1.** Install a Fresh OS and the old Windows will be on the C Drive in a folder named. Windows.old

Other Idea.

*Depending on the situation you can do the following.*

**2.** Boot into a live cd and mount a USB or External drive and backup the data you want to keep.

This is handy in situations where you need to copy files from one disc to another. Or you want to be safe and have it backed up just in case the windows install does not work.

Comment: I definitely recommend number 2. Coincidentally, I described the process a few hours earlier in this answer: http://superuser.com/a/1081492/278831